# NHibernate how to set a string type query-param for a named query

Tags: nhibernate, stored-procedures, parameters, mapping, varchar

I am calling a stored procedure through NHibernate. Everything is working except that it does not return any values when I try to set the stored procedure input parameter through code.

So for a stored procedure whose signature is like

```
dbo.sp_MySp @search_option char(10),  ......
```

### This works

mapping

```
    <sql-query name="sp_MySp">
      exec dbo.sp_MySp @search_option='ab', ...
    </sql-query>
```

code

```
var query = Session.GetNamedQuery("sp_MySp");

var results = query.List();
```

### This does not work

Mapping

```
<sql-query name="sp_MySp">
        <query-param name="search_option" type="String"/>
         exec dbo.sp_MySp @search_option=:search_option, ---
</sql-query>
```

code

```
var query = Session.GetNamedQuery("sp_MySp");

query.SetParameter("search_option", "ab");

var results = query.List();
```

Can someone point out what I am missing here....

Comment: I found out the issue. Guess query.SetParameter wasn't enough as it was probably not telling NHibernate the data type of the parameter. Changing it to query.SetAnsiString("search_option", "ab") made it to work. Woo Hoo!